# How to use stylePreprocessorOptions in Angular8

Tags: angular, angular8

[image]

I'am trying to learn how to use common css and js across two projects(project1,project2). I have googled it to call it under stylePreprocessorOptions in angular.json as shown below

```
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
      "includePaths": [
        "styles"
      ]
    },
```

and in image u can find the folder outside projects folder where i used check.css in that i gave

```
p{
  color:red
}
```

but its not get affecting my P tag  am i missing something please let me know how to use common css and js file across multiple project.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have one style.css that contains all CSS code and you want to import it into different components to use its code:

```
import "./../../code/styles.css";
```

Then you change your `angular.json` file to include the following:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
      "./code"
    ]
}
```

Afterwards, you can import simply like this:

```
import "styles";
```

Comment: ERROR in ./src/styles.css (C:/Users/harul/libraryCheck/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!C:/Users/harul/libraryCheck/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from C:/Users/harul/libraryCheck/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find 'check'
  in [
    C:\Users\harul\libraryCheck\projects\project1\src
  ]
    at C:\Users\harul\libraryCheck\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13
    at async Promise.all (index 0)

Comment: @import "check";
 
Hi i have mported like this